# Site Hangs Before Method Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to build a simple application that will ask for input based on a provided set of terms. It begins with the click of a button:

```
protected void InventoryMoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataDisplay.Text = "Inventory Move:";
    isDataStringMode = false;
    InstructionsLabel.Text = InventoryInstructions; //displays instruction text
    InventoryMove();
}
```

Which displays some text and calls `InventoryMove()`.

```
void InventoryMove()
{
    string[] keyList = { "FROM", "TO", "QUANTITY" }; //moving from somewhere to somewhere
    DataDisplay.Text = "hello from inventory move"; //this is a textbox
    BuildScreen("Inventory Move", BuildKeyList(keyList));
}
```

The method provides a list of terms for which it will require values from the user to the method `BuildScreen()`. `BuildKeyList()` simply takes those terms and puts them into an ArrayList, which `BuildScreen()` accepts. `BuildScreen()` is defined as follows:

```
void BuildScreen(string action, ArrayList listOfKeys)
{
    int input;
    DataDisplay.Text += "lol hi from BuildScreen";
    //DataTextBox.Text = "";
    DataDisplay.Text = action + "\n";

    //dataValues.Clear(); //empty previous values as they are not part of the current operation
    foreach (string key in listOfKeys)
    {
        DataDisplay.Text += key + ": ";
        input = readValidNumber();
        DataDisplay.Text += input + "\n";
        dataValues.Add(key, input);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that upon clicking the button, the `InstructionsLabel` text you see in my first bit of code never changes. So it seems the code is hanging at that point, but that could just be an error caused elsewhere before the text has the chance to change. Why is this code hanging when I click the button?

Comment: Are you using updatepanels?

Comment: No, I'm new to ASP.NET.